# Matlab template matching normxcorr2 error

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an homework that i need to identify playing cards with matlab.

I decide to use TemplateMatching using normxcorr2 but i keep having this error:

```
Error in Proje_Deneme2 (line 9)
R = normxcorr2(T,I);
```

And i dont know why.

here is my code:

```
I = imread("2clubs.jpg");
[Ir, Ic]=size(I);
figure(1)
imshow(I);
T = imread("2clubsTemp.jpg");
figure(2)
imshow(T);
[Tr, Tc]=size(T);
R = normxcorr2(T,I);
R = imcrop(R,[Tc Tr Ic Ir]);
[r, c, v] = fin(R==(max(max(R))));
RGB = insertShape(I, "rectangle", [c r Tc Tr], "LineWidth", 3);
figure(3)
imshow(RGB);
```

I am new to matlab and image processing and this is my first time using normxcorr2 so if i miss something very dump please excuse me.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Why aren't you posting the complete error message? I suppose it's "Error using normxcorr2. Expected input number 1, T, to be two-dimensional.".  Looks like I and T must be in Grayscale format (not RGB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i solve the problem my images are colored so when i perform grayscale on them it works.But i still don't know why colored images wont work.

Comment: The specific mathematical formula that is used for normalized cross-correlation is undefined for RGB input.